# Java RMI: Blocking for void method return?

Tags: java, rmi

I have an RMI interface that has a method with a void return.

For example:

```
public interface IDummy {
  public void foo() throws RemoteException;
}
```

I then create a stub via UnicastRemoteObject and export that stub.

Is it required in the RMI spec that calls to `foo` block until `foo` returns?
It seems like you would have to block in case `foo` throws an exception.
Even though the return type is void, `foo` might throw an exception which would have to be transported across as RMI is able to transfer arbitrary exceptions over.

However, I have heard conflicting reports that RMI does not have to block for a void return case.

Does anyone have a definitive answer?
I have already looked over the RMI [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmiTOC.html) and it does not seem to address this issue. [Some people](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17034) claim that it does not block.

In addition, I have read through the JDK source code and it definitely blocks even when the return value is void.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spec says:

> When a stub's method is invoked, it does the following:
>
> - initiates a connection with the remote JVM containing the remote object,
> - marshals (writes and transmits) the parameters to the remote JVM,
> - **waits for the result of the method invocation**,
> - **unmarshals (reads) the return value or exception returned**, and
> - returns the value to the caller.

(emphasis mine)

So yes, it must block.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it required in the RMI spec that calls to foo block until foo returns

It is required that *all* method calls block until they return. Nothing special about RMI here.